# c++: How to debug a C++ application compiled using the "Microsoft Visual C++" toolchain in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse CDT and CDT Visual C++ Support (from the Yoxos Marketplace).

This lets me compiled and run a C++ application, however, I cannot debug it.

So, I have installed a gdb windows binary using the mingw distribution. Now, when I try to debug, the following message is displayed in the console - **No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.**

My uneducated guess is that gdb cannot debug binaries produced by the Visual C++ compiler.

My question is - how do I debug C++ code in eclipse built using the Visual C++ toolchain?

My environment:

- Windows 7 64 bits
- Eclipse Indigo (the latest version at the moment)
- Visual Studio 2010, hence Visual C++ ver 10
- GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1
- I do not know how to get the version of CDT, but I have this jar - org.eclipse.cdt_8.0.0.201109151620.jar, so I guess the version is 8.0

Thanks.

**P.S.**

Moving to the MinGW g++ compiler is off scope for this question, so please - do not suggest it as the answer.

Comment: The symbols are not stored in the executable but in a separate database, probably an undocumented format.

Comment: It is PDB files - well known for Visual C++ developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you can't debug Visual C++ applications using gdb which is only supported by CDT plug-in.

Debugger for Visual C++ toolchain is called CDB and you have to search for the tool that can use it. For sure Visual C++ IDE (even from Express Edition) can be use to debug application that are compiled under Eclipse+CDT. I think that also some nightly builds of CodeBlocks IDE can cooperate with CDB.

Comment: I am looking to debug the code inside Eclipse. Is there a CDB integration there? From browsing the web I conclude that there is no such thing, but maybe your sources are better.

Comment: As I mentioned CDT doesn't support and Visual C++ compatible debugger. It only supports gdb. You have to use Visual C++ IDE or WinDbg (from Microsoft Debugging Tools) or maybe Codeblocks to debug application compiled by MS toolchain. There is no way to do this in Eclipse.

Comment: -1 for an incoherent and misleading answer; CDT is not the only tool that supports gdb. It is the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=162108

Summary: 
As of the last comment (Doug Schaefer 2012-03-13 10:49:27 EDT) in this bug it seems there are plans to integrate this but it is not yet working.