# VC++ allows /##/ as the value of a macro - how to deal with it in eclipse/mingw-gcc?

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc, mingw

I am trying to compile a real win32 application in eclipse/mingw-gcc, quite unsuccessfully until now (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162976/how-to-compile-a-win32-application-in-eclipse-using-the-mingw-gcc-toolchain)

Anyway, while troubleshooting yet another error, the following line in the file **c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\WTypes.h** has caught my curiosity:

```
#define _VARIANT_BOOL    /##/
```

It is used within the `struct tagVARIANT` from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\OAIdl.h**:

```
VARIANT_BOOL boolVal;
_VARIANT_BOOL bool;
SCODE scode;
```

which expands to:

```
VARIANT_BOOL boolVal;

SCODE scode;
```

Because `/##/` is expanded to `//`, which starts a comment! I do not believe it is compliant to the standard and indeed trying to compile in mingw-gcc fails with:

```
pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token   ComHelpers      line 445, external location: o:\C\wsdk\Include\oaidl.h  C/C++ Problem
```

So, I am looking for advices on how to solve this problem.

Comment: That must be some highly creative (ab)use of the preprocessor that I was previously unaware of

Comment: Why are you using the Windows SDK with a compiler other than VC++ in the first place? Use MinGW's [w32api](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/w32api/) package if you're using MinGW.

Comment: I have an existing win32 application, which is built with VS2010. I want to switch over to Eclipse, but I cannot make everyone in the team to follow suit - we are all too used to VS. I want to preserve the ability to compile in VS2010.

Comment: That's orthogonal to what was asked. VS will be configured to use the Windows SDK, as it should be, but you need to configure Eclipse to use w32api instead of the Windows SDK since it's compiling with GCC rather than VC++.

Comment: You'd better use `cl` with `Eclipse` than, not `mingw`, otherwise you often will face to troubles, that you'll have to solve instead of developing actual functionality.

Comment: I had to maintain cross-compiler code once. VS and GCC. It was a nightmare. People kept doing static varname = 1 because VS would assume that meant int, and GCC would throw an error. They wouldn't stop doing it.

Comment: @Lol4t0 - although eclipse has a Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain, it does not support the CDB debugger, hence using that toolchain makes debugging from the IDE impossible - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816923/c-how-to-debug-a-c-application-compiled-using-the-microsoft-visual-c-to.

Comment: @ildjarn - w32api does not seem to include com related headers, like **comdef.h**. Although, I am not writing a COM server, I am surely consuming one. Suggestions?

Comment: `how to solve this problem.` Just follow the sehe's advice : don't do that.

Comment: @VJovic - So much for the Eclipse being a great alternative for VS. At least, as long as win32/com development is involved.

Comment: @mark : I don't have any firsthand experience with consuming COM from MinGW so I don't have any concrete suggestions, but I think GCC would need to have an IDL compiler in order for that to work so it may not be possible at all.

Comment: @ildjarn - IDL compiler is needed when you produce COM, it is unnecessary when you consume COM. So, it is not a blocker.

Comment: comdef.h is helper for the #import directive.  Neither of which you'll have available.  The rewrite is pretty big, it is going to be a hard sell to your team mates.

Comment: Maybe, but there are no #import directives in the file itself or anything it references. My own code does not use imports either. I have already understood that we are not going to use Eclipse for our mainstream c++ development anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to figure out under what conditions the macro has the problem definition, and undef it in that case. If there's no way to tell, then just undef it unconditionally, and hope that's ok. :(

```
#include <problem-header.h>

#if whatever condition makes sense
#undef _VARIANT_BOOL
#endif

.....

#ifdef _VARIANT_BOOL
_VARIANT_BOOL bool;
#endif
```

Comment: I cannot remove anything. It is a system header.

Comment: Ick. You'll have to override it then. I'll edit the answer. Just a mo ,,,

Comment: Your answer would have made any sense if I controlled the usage of `_VARIANT_BOOL`. But it is used by **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\OAIdl.h**, which is a system header. Clearly, you are not suggesting me to edit it?

Comment: Well, no, but there comes a point when you have to copy it, edit it to make it sane, and ensure the compiler prefers to include your version over the standard one. :(