# Is it possible to develop and debug COM consuming C++ code on Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, winapi, com

Eclipse has a **Microsoft Visual C++** compiler toolchain, but does not support the CDB debugger, so it is possible to develop, but not debug (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816923/c-how-to-debug-a-c-application-compiled-using-the-microsoft-visual-c-to).

On the other hand, mingw has w32api, which lacks the COM support, so it is possible to develop and debug win32 applications, **which do not utilize the COM API**.

But what if I have a win32 c++ application, which does consume COM? Is there a way to develop and debug such an application in Eclipse?

Comment: I marked my answer for deletion. Totally off course, sorry!