# Refactoring C++ in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, refactoring, eclipse-cdt

I've installed the Galileo release (Eclipse 3.5/CDT 5.1) in hopes of utilizing the better refactoring support mentioned in

[What is the state of C++ refactor support in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130913/what-is-the-state-of-c-refactor-support-in-eclipse)

However I do not see all the mentioned refactoring options listed.  I don't see any plug-ins related to refactoring on

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/galileo

Attempts to add the plugin directly from the refactoring site fails http://ifs.hsr.ch/cdtrefactoring/updatesite/ due to outdated dependencies, so I'm assuming the newest release should have the latest refactoring abilities.

Am I correct in this?

How do others refactor in Eclipse CDT?  Do people use other tools/plugins?

Comment: Anybody find out anything more about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should install CDT 6.0. However, my guess is that the options mentioned in the question you linked are not yet ready for mainline.

My CDT offers Rename, Extract Variable/Constant/Function, Hide Method.

From those, I only use Rename regularly, the others do not yet seem finished.

One of the problems with such tools for C++ is that the language is way more complex than other languages (think templates, macros etc.) so implementing such a tool needs tremendously more effort than for, say, Java.