# Are there any tools for refactoring C++ to conform to coding standards?

Tags: c++, parsing, refactoring, naming-conventions

I need to process a large C++ codebase, renaming pretty much everything (classes, parameters, fields, methods, etc.). Do you know of any tools that could assist me in this job (apart from a text editor and a coffee maker)?

Comment: To clarify, by coding standards you mean the naming convention used at your company?

Comment: Windows-specific version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167/good-refactoring-support-for-c. It's either very similar to your problem or completely irrelevant, according to whether you're using Windows. Elsewhere you could try for example Eclipse. I guess what an IDE won't do, though, is propose things like "your coding standard says that data members are not permitted to have lower-case vowels in their names -- would you like me to rename `Foo::barInitializer` to `Foo:bAr_InItIAlIzEr`?". So enforcing "coding standards" *in general* no, enforcing common ones maybe.

Comment: Make sure nobody else has any uncommited changes during this, and that this codebase isn't used as a dependency of something else. "Renaming pretty much everything" is a good way to get chased by a pitchfork-wielding mob. Otherwise, it should be possible for an IDE to automate renames for a statically typed language: [CDT at least seems to have this feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194709/refactoring-c-in-eclipse-cdt#1194795).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio then you can use the plugin [Visual Assit X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for refactoring your code.
For indentation purposes you can use [indent](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/indent.htm) utility.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Semantic Designs C++ Tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/LanguageTools/CppTools.html) which seem to be pretty comprehensive although I've never used it.

It is rule based and understands the C++ language, rather than just being a reg exp search and replace utility, so it can do a whole lot more. The major caveat is that it's a commercial product, but the time it could save you and other longer term uses *might* be worth it to your company.

(BTW I have no connection to this company other than coming across it via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102610/c-refactoring-conditional-expansion-and-block-elimination).)

Answer (score 1):

Please, do not downvote and please, do not remove. This is not a plug. Original post is asking exactly for this.

Our company provides services in this area. I.e. we work with the customer to figure out exactly what his coding standards are. After that we tweak our toolkit that makes the refactoring. This is semiautomatic process. Some things are fixed with automatic refactoring, some things are fixed manualy.

For additional info please, look at out web site http://cdsan.com/Services.php#svcs_dycs

Comment: Actually, it is a plug. But if it really helps the OP, that's good enough. Not downvoting.